# Is it possible for a public-facing property to return either a string OR a numeric w/o using 'Object'?

Tags: vb.net

So I've run into a case where I have a class that can store either a string or a numeric value, and I want a single property to return one or the other (it would be a failure for both to be set).  I'm using a custom generic class to deal with the numerics (so I can use signed, unsigned, and nullables), and will be storing the string in a separate variable.

In theory, if overloading could be done based on the return type, I could do this quite easily.  But .NET currently disallows this.  So I am wondering if there is some other really-far-out-there trick (outside of MSIL generation via Reflection.Emit) that could accomplish the same thing.

I'm open to ideas via delegates, pointer dereferencing, generics, mystical rites, etc.  Also interested in any thoughts or pros/cons of such possibilities as a learning tool.  If using a standard Object is the only way to achieve what I want, then that's fine with me.  But It's difficult to find the correct set of keywords to hunt down this kind of capability on Google, so I thought I'd ask here before I moved on to doing something else on the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how using anything other than `Object` would work, for a simple property. Imagine you're the caller - what would you expect the declared type of the property to be? What type of value would you try to assign the expression to?

If you really *have* to have a single property which can return various different types, `Object` sounds like the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking is my only sane option.  I figured that with all the fanciness that .NET has, that it wouldn't be out of the realm of possibilities for the compiler to work with such properties and be able to know which specific overloaded property was being called.  I'm still learning the various names/keywords of specific .NET functionality, so I'm making sure that I am not missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the public property as string and also return the number after converting it to string.

```
public string YourProperty
{
    get { 
          if(somecondition)
                return "some string";
          else if(someothercondition)
                return 1234.ToString();
        }
}
```

while accessing your property you can use Convert.ToInt32().
Example:

```
public void YourMethod()
{
    int a;
    string str;
    bool isNumber;
    try
    {
      a = Convert.ToInt32(obj.YourProperty);
      isNumber = true;
    }
    catch(FormatException e)
    {
      str = obj.YourProperty;
      isNumber = false;
    }
}
```

Though this is not a good way programming, but you will acheive your objective of using only one property for both string and number.

Comment: Yeah, but that's for a getter only.  Setting would require me to check the bounds of the number in the string to make sure it would fit into the data type.  Technically, I'm in the same boat with an object.  It would just be cleaner if properties could support multiple return types in some form or fashion, or allow for overloading based on return type.  Or even allow generic properties, which should create unique-enough signatures.